# django rest_framework permission error

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm using dry-rest-permission package to write authentication for django webService. When I write permission method as same as the package docs I encounter internal server error and this :`'bool' object is not callable`
And this is my method:

```
  @staticmethod                                                                                                       
  @authenticated_users                                                                                                
  def has_create_permission(request):  
      return True
```

Comment: Post your full traceback, not just the exception message by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using incompatible version of dry-rest-permission with your current django framework. In `@authenticated_users` decorator `request.user.is_authenticated()` is called but in newer version of django `is_authenticated` has changed to a `bool` attribute from a function returning `bool`.

You could refer to their last [commits](https://github.com/dbkaplan/dry-rest-permissions/commit/98088dc61453b8603c6d567fa8702c99998fcd78) that correct usage of `is_authenticated`.

As it seems they doesn't release that commit yet you have to apply referred path manually to get rid of the error.

Comment: yep, that was exact problem. ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Per that page: "Using User.is_authenticated() and User.is_anonymous() as methods rather than properties is no longer supported."

Hope this can help you:

https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/200

Comment: I'm using is_authenticated as decorator, so it's a property not a method and it's supported